# Create a set containing the words in a text

Tags: java, string, set

I have to write a public class method called getWordsInString() for WebPageData. The method takes a single argument called text which should be of type String. The purpose of getWordsInString() is to return a set consisting of the distict words that are in the string referenced by text.

First make use of the method you found in Javadoc for the String class that will chop any string into a number of parts depending on the value of its string argument. Use this method  to break up the string referenced by text into an array of words and assign this array to a local variable called wordArray. The method should declare a local variable capable of referencing a set of strings and assign to it an empty instance of a suitable class. Next iterate over wordArray and add its elements to the newly created set and finally return the set which should contain the distinct words that are in the string referenced by text.

```
import java.util.*;

public class WebPageData {

private Set<String> wordSet;
private Set<String> url;

public Set<String> getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public Set<String> getWordSet() {
    return wordSet;
}

public static String getWordsInString(text) {
    return test;



public String[] split(String regex) {

            private String[] wordArray;

for (String eachText : numSet) {
    hashSet.add(text);
    ) 
   }
```

I'm struggling with this question, please help?

Comment: What bit in particular?  The iteration looks OK, and String.split is definitely the place to start.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is it that you're struggling with? We're not here to write your homework for you.

Comment: do you know how to split the text into words? If not, then check out 'whitespace' (and how to do it in regex)

Comment: I'm struggling with writing the getWordsInString() method :(

Answer (score 13):

You only need one line to do everything:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(text.split(" +")));
```

Or in java 8:

```
Set<String> set = Arrays.stream(text.split(" +")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have lot of syntaxic errors in your code :

- Class WebPageData is missing closing braces.
- Method getWordsInString is missing closing braces.
- Method split is missing closing braces
- wordArray is a local variable, it shouldn't use the keyword private.
- You have a closing parens after "hashSet.add(text);"
- hashSet variable is not declared.
- Your split method declare that it return an Array of String but is
  missing a return statement.

To be syntaxically correct you should write something like:

```
import java.util.*;

public class WebPageData {

    private Set<String> wordSet;
    private Set<String> url;

    public Set<String> getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public Set<String> getWordSet() {
        return wordSet;
    }

    public static String getWordsInString(text) {
        String[] wordArray;
        return test;
    }

    public String[] split(String regex) {
        String[] wordArray;
        Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();

        for (String eachText : numSet) {
            hashSet.add(text);
        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

This is now syntaxically correct, but is not was you want.

Here is a correct getWordsInString method:

```
public Set<String> getWordsInString(String text) {
    String[] wordArray = text.split(" ");
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String currentWord : wordArray) {
      set.add(currentWord);
    }
    return set;
}
```

Here is maybe a less verbose way to do it (but this is not you are required to do):

```
public Set<String> getWordsInString(String text) {
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));
    return new HashSet(words);
}
```

I prefer this second version because it concentrate of what you want, convert your array to a set. The other go into the detail of iterating the full list. You'll prefer the first version when performance is an important concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Set<String> getWordSet(String input) {
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    Set wordSet=new Set();
    for(int i =0; i<words.length;i++){//length or size() :S im not sure
        wordSet.add(words[i]);
    }

    return wordSet;
}
```

i dont test it

Answer (score 0):

```
public Set<String> getWordSet(String input) {
    return new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")));
}
```

There is a performance penalty here for creating a (temporary) list, but for typical cases it should not be a problem.